# AJAX , PHP , chat creating

Tags: php, ajax

I recently created this .html file :

> ```
> <?php
> ?>
>
> <html>
> <head>
> <title>Feri`s Chat</title>
> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
> <script>
>
> function submitChat(){
> if(form1.uname.value == '' || form1.msg.value == ''){
> alert('Kerlek irj be egy nevet es egy uzenetet is :S');
> return;
> }
>
> var uname = form1.uname.value;
> var msg = form1.msg.value;
> var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
>
> xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
>
> if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200){
> document.getElementById('chatlogs').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;}
>
> }
>
>
>
> xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php?uname="+uname+"&msg="+msg,true);
> xmlhttp.send();
>
> }
>
>
> $(document).ready(function(e) {
> $.ajaxSetup({cache:false)};
> setInterval(function(){$(#chatlogs).load('lel.php')};);
>
> )};
>
>
>
>
> </script>
>
> </head>
> <body>
> <form name="form1">
> Ird be a chat neved: <input type="text" name="uname" />
>
> Az uzeneted :
>
> <textarea name="msg"></textarea>
>
> <a href="#" onClick="submitChat()">Kuld</a>
>
>
>
> <div id="chatlogs">
> Keressuk az uzeneteket, kerlek varj...
> </div>
>
> </body>
> ```

It`s chat.
Now, heres what really bothers me.
On the 36th line where i wrote : "

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false)};
setInterval(function(){$(#chatlogs).load('lel.php')};);

)};
```

"
I get something named a SYNTAX ERROR . And I just can`t figure out what the problem is .
Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the selector you're using:

```
$(#chatlogs)
```

What is `#chatlogs`?  Where do you define it?  Can JavaScript variables even use a `#` character?  I doubt they can.

Or, most likely, you probably meant to use that as a jQuery selector string:

```
$('#chatlogs')
```

**Edit:** Also, look at this line:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false)};
```

Specifically look at the order in which you open and close your parentheses and braces:

```
({)}
```

You need to close containing characters in the stack order in which they were opened, from inner to outer:

```
({})
```

thus:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
```

Comment: Thank you David for your fast reply , I was sure there`s something not right with that line either , that`s why I asked the question like that. I corrected it , but there still is a syntax error on line 36 specifically with the following line <"$.ajaxSetup({cache:false)};">

Comment: @FeRi: I've updated my answer to include that.  Looks like it was just a typo you overlooked.

Comment: It seems like I had totally messed up with this part of the code. Could I gently ask you to check this line too , again `code`setInterval(function(){$('#chatlogs').load('lel.php')};);
    
 )};`code` since it is still warning me of a syntax error. I`m really sorry to bother you with such things :(

Comment: @FeRi: It's the same exact error.  You're opening a `(` and a `{` and then closing them in the wrong order.  I can understand missing this once as a typo, but come on.  You need to put in at least *some* effort here.

Comment: Thank you @David for helping me out . I really appriciate it.